# How to get all the dates displayed in a QCalendarWidget

Tags: c++, qt, calendar

I am using a QCalendarWidget in my application, and I overloaded the updateCells method to put a red background on every dates which meet certain conditions.

My problem is I don't know how to get the first date **displayed** in the calendar (not the first date in the month), and the last date **displayed**.
Example: in february, the first date displayed is january the 25th, and the last date displayed is march the 7th.

There isn't any useful method in QCalendarWidget and I can't think of an algorithm for this.
Do you have any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

As you've got access to the currently shown month and year, you can use the [QDate::dayOfWeek](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdate.html#dayOfWeek) on the first and last date of the shown contents. Taking [QCalendarWidget::firstDayOfWeek](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qcalendarwidget.html#firstDayOfWeek-prop) into account, you aught to be able to decide how far back and forth you have to go.

Answer (score 0):

QCalendarWidget class is a combination of more simple widgets, you can see Qt source code for help. Just use loop to get all dates between:

```
class myQCalendar(QCalendarWidget):
    """custum QCalendarWidget"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.table = self.findChild(QTableView)

    def return_first_last_dates(self) -> Tuple[QDate, QDate]:
        # first row(0) and col(0) - headers, so we use second(1,1)
        first_date = self.date_by_index(
            self.table.model().index(1, 1)) 
        last_date = self.date_by_index(
            self.table.model().index(6, 7))
        return first_date, last_date
        # self.table.model().dateForCell(1,1) didn't work in python 
        # maybe it will work in c++


    def date_by_index(self, index: QModelIndex) -> QDate:
        """ Return QDate by index of model of QTableView """
        date = self.selectedDate()
        day = int(index.data())
        mnth = date.month()  # current month always the same as current date
        if day > 15 and index.row() < 3:  # qcalendar always display 6 rows( and 0 - is header)
            mnth = date.month() - 1
        if day < 15 and index.row() > 4:
            mnth = date.month() + 1
        return QDate(date.year(), mnth, day)
```